# User-defined harmonic mean function performs worse than query in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql, functions, aggregate, postgresql-9.6

We created a harmonic mean function based on [this blog post](https://tim.mcnamara.nz/post/177172657187/user-defined-aggregates-in-postgresql):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.harmean_accum(numeric[], numeric)
RETURNS numeric[]
LANGUAGE sql STABLE COST 1
AS $h$
SELECT array[$1[1]+1.0/$2, $1[2]+1.0]; 
$h$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.harmean_finalize(numeric[])
RETURNS numeric
LANGUAGE sql STABLE COST 1
AS $h$
SELECT $1[2] /  $1[1];
$h$;

CREATE AGGREGATE public.harmean(numeric) (
    sfunc = public.harmean_accum,
    stype = numeric[],
    finalfunc = public.harmean_finalize,
    INITCOND = '{0.0, 0.0}'
);
```

But when we compare the performance of using this user-defined function in a query, it's >6x worse:

```
SELECT category, harmean(spd)
FROM spds
GROUP BY category
```

vs

```
SELECT category, COUNT(spd)/SUM(1/spd)
FROM spds
GROUP BY category
```

The `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` doesn't really give insight into what might be slowing down the user-generated aggregate.

Comment: There is a substantial overhead in calling a function not written in C, so yes this is expected. **Maybe** this gets a bit better when using Postgres 11 with JIT enabled, but I doubt it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, so we defining the `sfunc` and `finalfunc` in C could boost performance? Alas we can't test this because we're using AWS RDS.

Comment: Could the numeric type be part of the problem? i.e. would it be more efficient to implement the function for real or double-precision numbers?

Comment: Good point, the conversion and then operations on a data type with arbitrary precision could be the cost. We could use function overloading to have this function work for each relevant numeric type. If you test a solution feel free to answer and I will accept it